# reading plist with nsbundle, in one case it works and in an almost similar case it doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c

Could someone tell me why this code works:

```
        ..non-relevant previous code
       [self readPlist:@"s_a.plist"];
    }
}

- (void)readPlist: (NSString *)fileName{
NSString *bundleString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *plistPath = [bundleString stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

But the following returns nil?

```
        [self readPlist:@"s_a.plist"]; 
    }
}

- (void)readPlist: (NSString *)fileName{ 
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

To me it seems that I'm doing the same thing. I've been looking at several SO solutions, and I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 [self readPlist:@"s_a.plist"]; 

 NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"plist"];
```

you are passing **s_al.plist** as fileName so the method now looks for **s_a.plist.plist** which it fails

Comment: I didn't see that coming. Thanks :)